# Sum a number on key type javascript

Tags: javascript, sum

I have an auto update sum form which is runs perfectly with 3 inputs. But I need one more input to be calculated. I tried to add a field and tried to mimic the script but have no luck. Please help.

```
function formatDollar(num) {
    var p = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
    return "" + p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
        return  num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
    }, "");
}
    //auto sum
function calculateDiscount()
{
    var cost = document.getElementById('insr_total1').value.replace(/[^0-9]+/i,"");
        cost = cost.replace(/[^0-9]+/i,"");         
    var discount = document.getElementById('insr_discount').value;
    //do the math
    var net = cost-discount;
    //update
    document.getElementById('insr_discount2').innerHTML = formatDollar(cost*(discount/100));
    document.getElementById('insr_total3').value = formatDollar(cost-cost*(discount/100));
}
```

And this is the html I use with:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">Cost1</td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="insr_total1" id="insr_total1" size="17" maxlength="15" onKeyup="calculateDiscount(); return false;" /> USD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">Discount</td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="insr_discount" id="insr_discount" size="4" maxlength="3"  onkeyup="calculateDiscount(); return false;" /> % (<span id="insr_discount2" style="color:green; font-size: 13px;"></span> USD)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">Cost 2</td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="insr_total2" id="insr_total2" size="17" maxlength="15"  /> USD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">Overall</td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="insr_total3" id="insr_total3" size="17" readonly maxlength="15"  /> USD</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Well, I need "insr_total2" to subtract from insr_total3. It always gets error no matter I tried. Appreciated for all reply.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? Can you approve one of the answers below?

Comment: No Bart, It's still not working. I still need a hand.

Answer (score 1):

use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert strings into numbers first and check if they are not NaN with [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```
var number1 = parseFloat(value1) * 100
  , number2 = parseFloat(value2) * 100
  , result = (number1 - number2) / 100;
```

And be careful with decimals and calculations in JavaScript. It is better to multiply the number first with 100 or 1000 (depending on the precision you need). Otherwise you will get rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

The values you have are strings and you are trying to subtract one from the other. You'll need to convert to a float:

var discount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('insr_discount').value);

etc...

Comment: Define "gone weird". Please put what you have on jsfiddle so I can see something running.

Comment: Lee, Please have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/B2cCg/
Wierd means it doesn't results as I expect. When I put a currency in Cost1 the same number should appear in Overall. After do the math "Discount". So Overall=Cost1-(Discount+Cost2). Please help.